# How can i fetch audios from Soundcloud?

Tags: android, audio, fetch, soundcloud

I have the code to upload audios to SoundCloud from my app..But my project requires to fetch audios from soundcloud and display in my android app..I can't find any tutorial for this..How can i fetch audios from Soundcloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SoundCloud HTTP API Reference](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users)

Check the Subresources section

Comment: How to use these api in my app?i am fresher in android..

Comment: For that you'll need to learn how to make web requests from Android. Plenty of tutorials/libraries out there.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/.. is this the way i should do that?

Comment: That looks like the simplest approach, everything on Android can be done in many ways (thanks to Java). Web requests are usually done on a background thread not on the UI thread. Maybe you'll be able to find how to do web requests via an AsyncTask. Good luck in your endeavors and accept the answer if you wish

Comment: +1 for ur answer..i'll wait for other answers..here i have to replace uri inside HttpPost by the uri "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/3207.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" and nameValuePair by pairs given in document like "id": 3207,
  "permalink": "jwagener",
  "username": "Johannes Wagener"????